# Why Do we need to change the handlers in web.config while using the telerik controls

Tags: telerik

I have a question, as on why do we need to add handelers to web.config file while working with telerik controls

what is the significance of the following code?

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

and another question is that in the  section why do we remove the asset handler first and then immediately add it again?

```
<handlers>
<remove name="asset" />
<add name="asset" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.axd files are HTTP handler files and Telerik probably use them for managing their scripts and assets such as images and stylesheets for their skins.
This handler has to be registered in the web.config so it's executed when the browser requests this file and to ensure it's directed to the approperate HTTP handler. Telerik controls behind the scenes can then safely assume the assets are available.

If you view the generate html source of your application you'll probably see references to asset.axd?blah==3dfijefi if you view the contents of this file you'll see exactly what's going on (although probably minified).

As for why they suggest removing and adding again I suspect it's to stop parent web.config files that may reference older versions etc... ? Just a safety net really.